# date_create_from_format() returns wrong value.

Tags: php

This is my simple code to say the month in words

```
<?php
    $date = date_create_from_format('m', '12');
    $numw = $date->format('F');
    echo $numw;// december
?>
```

it works well and good expect February. It return march

```
<?php
    $date = date_create_from_format('m', '02');
    $numw = $date->format('F');
    echo $numw;// march
?>
```

how to solve this issue. this is a PHP pre defined functions. is it working wrong or i am using it wrong ?

Comment: What is the problem ? you change the date format to F (display month text), then you output.

Comment: @VincentDecaux: it returns march . but it should return February

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the current default date is 30rd and February doesn't go that far. And then it assumes it's in March.

This is mentioned on the  **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)** as well.

> If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the generated time which are not specified in format will be set to the current system time.

You're best off by also defining the day of the month.

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d-m', '01-02');
```

Comment: Very nice thinking :) Do you mind the edit?

Comment: No sir, I do not. We're here to help :)